# Angular, Node JS problem when put app on server

Tags: node.js, angular, cpanel

I get this error: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

I call my api like:  `http://localhost:3000/something...`

Should I call it on different way since it is on server instead on localhost?

Comment: You need to change the `URL` for your API. What is the URL for your API now?

Comment: So you think that I have to call my api like http://myDomain/something Instead of http://localhost/...

Comment: Yes, How are you running your angular app and where?  You need to make changes to the URL. Why don't you use the env config to make change automatically.

Comment: Now, I running my angular app on real server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to create a env config file, when you are on prod mode changes the base URL to `http://mydomain/something`. When you create a build with `prod` cmd line in angular the base URL will be picked up from the 'env' file.

Angular does provide you environment file `environments/environments.prod.ts`

```
export const environment = {  
  apiUrl: 'http://my-api-url',
  enableDebug: false
};
```

You can check [here](https://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-to-configure-your-angular-application-without-a-rebuild/#:%7E:text=export%20const%20environment%20%3D%20%7B%20apiUrl%3A,prod.) for more details.